# Flutter - push notifications appearing in iOS in debug mode but not in release mode

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, release-mode

I am currently using the flutter_apns (https://github.com/mwaylabs/flutter-apns) package to show push alerts in iOS in my flutter app. Everything works great in debug mode, however when I test in release mode, the alerts do not appear.

This is despite the fact that I have:

- Push Notifications enabled
- Background fetch and remote notifications enabled

both in debug and release mode

I am using:

```
flutter_apns: ^1.5.1
firebase_messaging: ^10.0.2
```

In my Info.plist I have tried adding:

```
    <key>flutter_apns.disable_firebase_core</key>
    <false/>
    <key>flutter_apns.disable_swizzling</key>
    <false/>
```

I also tried this in the Info.plist but again nothing:

```
<key>flutter_apns.disable_firebase_core</key>
<false/>
<key>flutter_apns.disable_swizzling</key>
<true/>
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
<key>FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

My Flutter doctor summary:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.2.1 20D74 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

I am using Xcode 12.5.1 and running iPadOs 14.7.1.

Anyone come across this issue? Any help would be much appreciated